# Immediately redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, redirect

There is a simply page with some `<a>` tags, click on all of them redirected to some pages(for example there are urls from `A` group). I want to change redirected URL from some `<a>` tags to another url, for example fom `B` group(this is not my code and I can not modify it).
I added 'on click' method to context:

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
    var name = $(e.target).text();
    if(name = aWithNewRedirectUrl){
        window.location.href = newUrl;
    }        
});
```

and everything works fine on firefox - onClick event opens url from `B` group (if it exists) but problem is with Chrome - onClick opens for some time(~1s but user can see it) url from `A` group and then redirect to url from `B`). Is there any way to avoid open `A` url effect on Chrome?

Comment: try use `e.preventDefault()` before redirect, other way is why u dont want to change url in a element ?

Comment: I dont have permission to this code

Comment: but u can use js to do this??

Comment: yes, I can not modify 'main code' but can add some scripts for context

Comment: What is the reason you can't change the code?